# What are the minimal criteria required to be appointed as a Supreme Court Justice by the U.S. President?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, nomination

What are the minimal criteria required to be appointed as a Supreme Court Justice by the U.S. President? Do you have to serve a certain year? What's the minimum position you must have held? I see that all of them were either Chief Justice or Associate. Is it possible to have a lower position and still be appointed or is there a minimum set of requirements required by law?